# How to drag an element inside a parent container without using draggable events?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to drag the (el) div element within the dashed border div. I am trying to get the working logic for this.

The link is as follows:
https://jsfiddle.net/k8rt1yvx/7/

I have already tried setting child.offsetY-parent-offsetY codes.

> html code (part of code)

```
`<div class="subbox" ng-mousemove="mouse_move1($event)">
<div class="element" ng-mousemove="mouse_move2($event)">`
```

> javascript (part of code)

```
var mouse_x=0;
var mouse_y=0;
var el=document.getElementsByClassName('element');

$scope.mouse_move1=function(event)
{
   if(angular.element(event.target).hasClass('subbox'))
    {
       mouse_x=event.offsetX;
       mouse_y=event.offsetY;      
    }
};

$scope.mouse_move2=function(event)
 {
   if(event.buttons==1) //for left button click
     {
         var offset_x = event.offsetX;
         var offset_y = event.offsetY; 
         var drag_x   = mouse_x + offset_x;
         var drag_y   = mouse_y + offset_y;
         angular.element(el).css('top',drag_x+"px");
         angular.element(el).css('left',drag_y+"px");          
     }
 };
```

I don't get it how to make el draggble only in the subbox div.